# Conditional display of css container

Tags: php, css, woocommerce

**EDIT** :  I use `return true;` in the first function and `if(fonction1() === true)` in the second.
However it **displays me the boolean value at the front-end**, namely "1". Any idea how not to display this?

---

I'm trying to do this with this code:

Here is my code with my try but it doesn't work (the "if" "else" should just allow to change the associated css class)

```
// Sales badge
add_action( 'woocommerce_sale_flash', 'sale_badge_percentage', 25 );
 
function sale_badge_percentage() {
   global $product;
   if ( ! $product->is_on_sale() ) return;
   if ( $product->is_type( 'simple' ) ) {
      $max_percentage = ( ( $product->get_regular_price() - $product->get_sale_price() ) / $product->get_regular_price() ) * 100;
   } elseif ( $product->is_type( 'variable' ) ) {
      $max_percentage = 0;
      foreach ( $product->get_children() as $child_id ) {
         $variation = wc_get_product( $child_id );
         $price = $variation->get_regular_price();
         $sale = $variation->get_sale_price();
         if ( $price != 0 && ! empty( $sale ) ) $percentage = ( $price - $sale ) / $price * 100;
         if ( $percentage > $max_percentage ) {
            $max_percentage = $percentage;
         }
      }
   }
   if ( $max_percentage > 0 ) {
        echo "<span class='onsale'>-" . round($max_percentage) . "%</span>"; 
        return true;
   }
}




// New badge for recent products
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item_title', 'new_badge', 3 );
          
function new_badge() {
   if(sale_badge_percentage() === true) {
    /* la variable existe */
       global $product;
   $newness_days = 30; // Number of days the badge is shown
   $created = strtotime( $product->get_date_created() );
   if ( ( time() - ( 60 * 60 * 24 * $newness_days ) ) < $created ) {
      echo '<span class="ct-woo-card-extra new-badge">' . esc_html__( 'NEW', 'woocommerce' ) . '</span>';
   }
}
else {
    /* la variable n'existe pas */
    global $product;
   $newness_days = 30; // Number of days the badge is shown
   $created = strtotime( $product->get_date_created() );
   if ( ( time() - ( 60 * 60 * 24 * $newness_days ) ) < $created ) {
      echo '<span class="ct-woo-card-extra new-badge solobadge">' . esc_html__( 'NEW', 'woocommerce' ) . '</span>';
   }
}
}
```

Comment: PHP is irrelevant to the question, since CSS works with HTML (that PHP has generated and sent to the client); can you post the "*[mcve]*" HTML and CSS, please? Also, while I appreciate that English may not be your first language - and may well be difficult for you - question on Stack Overflow *must* be in the English language; could you please translate your French into English?

Comment: @DavidThomas Hello, indeed my question was incomplete. I have completely reformulated it with a much simpler request. 

You can see the modification directly in my original question.

And sorry for my English, I try to translate the best I can

Comment: There are a couple problems: `$max_percentage` is never set - since it is not being passed to `new_badge()` anywhere.  Also, you gave us two functions, but it isn't clear where you actually need to check `$max_percentage`

Comment: @disinfor Yes,I just tried and even with ```$max_percentage``` set, it doesn't work.

In fact I just want that : if "SALES" badge exists then assign the css class "ct-woo-card-extra new-badge" to the "NEW" badge. And if "SALES" badge does not exist then assign the css class "ct-woo-card-extra new-badge-solo".

Only I don't know how to check if "SOLDES" exists, I tried with an isset but I must be wrong somewhere.
The badges I'm talking about are two different functions (which are in my question above)

Comment: Please update your code in this question with what you tried (setting `$max_percentage`). We need to see what you're trying.

Comment: That's ok, so I defined the variable ```$max_percentage``` in function #2. I also tried something else that you can see with ```$testtrue = true;``` and ```if ( $testtrue == true);```

Comment: Ok I just found a solution that works: with ```return true;``` in the first function (code updated above) and ```if(fonction1() === true)```
However it displays me the boolean value at the front, namely "1". Any idea how not to display this?